# Setting C++ build working directory in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, working-directory, waf

I am trying to set up a C++ project in Eclipse (on Windows) that uses Waf to build. My Eclipse workspace and my source files are in different directories.

- `C:\myproject`: Project root
- `C:\myproject\wscript`: Waf build script
- `C:\myproject\source`: Source code
- `C:\myproject\project\eclipse`: Eclipse Workspace
- `C:\myproject\project\eclipse\myproject`: Eclipse Project

Waf must be executed from the directory that contains `wscript`.

In my project properties, under `C/C++ Build`, my Build command should be `python waf`. I created a temporary script at `C:\myproject\temp.cmd` just containing `pwd`, and set the Build command to `..\..\..\temp.cmd` in order to confirm what the working directory is. The build console shows `C:\myproject\project\eclipse\myproject` when I run the build.

How can I change this so that it will show `C:\myproject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a wrapper script that sets the proper working directory.

*C:\myproject\project\eclipse\waf.cmd*

```
@ECHO OFF
CD ..\..\..
python waf %*
```

In Eclipse I set Build command to `${WorkspaceDirPath}/waf.cmd`.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether you need to restore the working directory at the end of the script. I wouldn't think so since Eclipse is likely creating a new process just for the build that then expires at the end of the script.

Answer (score -1):

In `C/C++ Build` you can set `Build directory`. Enter `C:\myproject` there. The build command must be in your PATH for it to work.

Comment: This does not work. I believe this field is for build output. I set `Build directory` to `C:\myproject` and set `Build command` to `temp.cmd`, but then Eclipse claims it can't find `temp.cmd`.

Comment: If you make sure that temp.cmd is in your PATH it will work (or just use the full path in your build command). At least it did for me.